# Infinite sum of mobius function

Tags: number-theory, mobius-inversion

Show that if $|q| < 1$, then $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}} \frac{\mu(n)*q^n}{1-q^n} = q$.

I have a feeling that $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}q^n = \frac{1}{1-q}$ (for $|q|<1$) is going to make an appearance, but from there I am not sure.

As $n$ gets larger, the denominator will approach $1$ and the nominator will approach $0$. But I am not sure if that helps, since this is a sum, not a limit. I can't see how that would help me get $q$.

Comment: Can i sub in $\frac{1}{1-q}$ and then pull them outside the sum since they are not dependent on $n$? It would look something like $\frac{q}{1-q}\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\mu(n)$

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty simple:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)q^n}{1-q^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\mu(n)q^{nt} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)q^{n}=q$$
Caused by the simple lemma:

For $n>1$ the 
$$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)=0$$
and for $n=1$
$$\sum_{d|1}\mu(d)=1$$

In general this is the particular case of Lambert series.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series